# How can I format my functions so that I dont get an undefined error

Tags: python, function, tkinter, formatting

This is one of my functions here, Im using tkinter to make some pop up tabs, but I the variable "attempt" is staying at 0, its not changing when I input something. I know this is an issue with my function formatting, I dont quite understand how functions work yet. Ive tried using "return" but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
def buttonn5():
    def submit():
        if attempt == password:
            print("yes")
    newpass = tkinter.Tk()
    newpass.title("Entry")
    newpass.geometry("500x300")
    password = "Sam24"
    sumbit = tkinter.Button(newpass, text="Submit", command = submit, height=1, width = 10)
    attempt = 0
    title1 = Label(newpass, text="Password")
    textbox1 = tkinter.Entry(newpass, textvariable=attempt)
    title1.pack(side="top")
    textbox1.pack(side="top")
    sumbit.pack(side="top")
```

I don't get any output when I run this and put the right password in.

Comment: It is generally helpful to provide your `import` statements because they are important.  With just your function its difficult to help you.  For starters it look like you named your nested function `submit` and then also create a variable named `submit` which is something you should not do. Objects should have unique names to prevent namespace pollution.  I am also not sure why you are using a nested function at all.  From what I see its unnecessary.

Comment: If your goal is to take a value that is entered by a user into your `Entry` and then have that value stored in a variable you need to use the `get()` method to grab the value from the entry and then you can do something with it.  If you are trying to count the number or try's the user makes and store that number in your variable `attempt` then you need to have a running count and update your variable with each count.